# Problema con DNS en un AD DC

Tags: servidor, dns, windows-server-2012

Tengo un problema que no entiendo. Agradeceria ayuda.

La cosa es asi.

Tengo un Windows server 2012, con un AD DC y ahi mismo un DNS. 
El nombre de la maquina es: ws.
El dominio es: dom.inetserver.lo
El NETBIOS del dominio es DOM.
El IP: 192.168.10.4

En el DNS la zona primera de busqueda es: dom.inetserver.lo

```
Nombre  Tipo    Datos
    (igual que la carpeta principal)    Inicio de autoridad (SOA)   [5], ws.dom.inetserver.lo., hostmaster.
    (igual que la carpeta principal)    Servidor de nombres (NS)    ws.dom.inetserver.lo.
    ws  Host (A)    192.168.10.4
```

Un nslookup desde el propio server para: ws.dom.inetserver.lo responde sin problemas 192.168.10.4. Si hago lo mismo desde una PC en la red, responde igual. Si pregunto por ws, asi sin el sujifo (dom.inetserver.lo), no responde.

Tengo un Win7 en una VM que incluyo en el dominio sin problemas. Pero. Y aqui es donde se pone raro. Intento incluir un NAS Qnap.

Cuando uso:
nombre completo del dominio DNS: dom.inetserver.lo
nombre NETBIOS: DOM

El NAS dice que no encuentra la informacion necesaria.

Cuando uso:
nombre completo del dominio DNS: ws.dom.inetserver.lo
nombre NETBIOS: DOM

el NAS detecta el nombre del bosque de AD DC (ws.dom.inetserver.lo) pero a la hora de uninerse pone algo que no entiendo, esto lo que pone:

servidor DNS: 192.168.10.4
nombre DNS: ws.dom.inetserver.lo
nombre NETBIOS: DOM
controlador de dominio ws.ws.dom.inetserver.lo

agrega un WS delante..

Las maquinas Windows se unen sin problemas lo que me dices que mi configuracion del del DNS y el AD DC es correcta. Entonces no entiendo porque un NAS hace ese cambio.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.